# Insert columns value into hstore data type in postgres

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a table in postgres which has this three columns id_0,turnr and tags. tags column data type is hstore.
currently i am using this query which is not working

```
INSERT INTO relation_15_02_2020 (tags)
VALUES
   (
   '
       "type"=>"restriction",
       "restriction"=>"(select distinct(turnr) from relation_15_02_2020  ) "
       '
   );
```

How can i add

```
"type"=>"restriction",
"restriction"=>" turnr value for respective id
```

desired output for id_0 =1 tags

```
 {"type"=>"restriction","restriction"=>"NoRightTurn"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update the rows, not insert new ones:

```
update relation_15_02_2020 
  set tags = hstore(array['type', 'restriction'], array['restriction', turnr])
where id_0 = 1;
```

alternatively

```
update relation_15_02_2020 
  set tags = hstore('type', 'restriction')||hstore('restriction', turnr)
where id_0 = 1;
```

Comment: @poonampatel: if you don't want to overwrite the existing value, but append the new keys, use `set tags = tags || ....`